# cannot open /usr/share/dbconfig-common/internal/mysql: No such file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, kali-linux

Good afternoon all. Iḿ having this problem in a debian OS

Setting up phpmyadmin (4:4.9.7+dfsg1-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/phpmyadmin.config: 144: .: cannot open /usr/share/dbconfig-common/internal/mysql: No such file
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--configure):
installed phpmyadmin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
phpmyadmin

- Already tryied to force, and already reinstaled mysql and mysql is running, but phpmyadmin doens´t work.
- sudo apt-get clean
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo dpkg -r mysql-client-5.7
  sudo dpkg -r mysql-server-5.7
  sudo dpkg -r libmysqlclient20:i386
  sudo dpkg -r libmysqlclient20:amd64
  sudo dpkg -r libmysqlclient18:amd64
  sudo dpkg -r mysql-common
  sudo dpkg -r mysql

apt upgrade and aptitude --fix-missing and nothing worked

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That file is provided by `dbconfig-common`, so while I have no idea why it's missing in the first place, you should be able to fix it with `apt-get install --reinstall dbconfig-common`.

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dbconfig-common` if get permission denied / root user error

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when I was trying to uninstall phpmyadmin.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/dbconfig-common/internal/mysql

sudo apt-get install --reinstall dbconfig-common
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

- sudo mkdir mysql
- sudo apt-get install --reinstall dbconfig-common

Comment: Please make the additional insight more obvious, which you contribute beyond  existing answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).